# Python - Assign function to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I use the module **subprocess** to show status of firewall :

```
subprocess.check_call('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state')
```

But it always show the output to screen like this :

```
Domain Profile Settings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Private Profile Settings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
Public Profile Settings: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
State                                 ON
```

I just one to assign it to a variable to get only "ON" or "OFF" status of Firewall.

I try all the way i know but it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to parse the data coming in from the output.
here a simple example

```
DESCRIPTION = slice(0, 25)
STATUS = slice(25, 40)

result = subprocess.getoutput('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state')
iterable = result.splice('\n')
elements = {}
for line in iterable:
    if 'Settings' not in line:
        continue
    name = line[DESCRIPTION].strip()
    line_break = next(iterable)
    status = next(iterable)[STATUS].strip()
    elements[name] = status
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\OneDrive\Dropbox\Learning\Gradutate\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    iterable = result.splice('\n')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splice'

Comment: It not working pax80. You cannot assign "subprocess.check_call('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state')" to result just that easily. I already try this. But, thanks for helps

Comment: Is your output a list of lines? I created a dummy as multiline string separated by ‘\’. What is the type returned by the subprocess  check call?

Comment: I don't sure it a list or just lines. The output just like you run "netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state" on CMD. Although you have assign "subprocess.check_call('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state')" to variable result but values of result still 0 . That why "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'splice'" show up when i run your code.

Comment: @Quang Le 

you can use *subprocess.getoutput()* in this case you will work on the output received

the subprocess.check_call() will return the return code of the result of the command. 


    _result =  subprocess.getoutput('netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state')_

Comment: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getoutput'" i get this. I thinks this error show up cause subprocess have no function name getoutput right ?

Comment: i am using python 3.6.2

help(subprocess.getoutput)

*Help on function getoutput in module subprocess:

getoutput(cmd)
    Return output (stdout or stderr) of executing cmd in a shell.

    Like getstatusoutput(), except the exit status is ignored and the return
    value is a string containing the command's output.  Example:

    >>> import subprocess
    >>> subprocess.getoutput('ls /bin/ls')
    '/bin/ls'*

Comment: i am using python 2.7. That would be the reason why the error show up. Thanks pax80